# How to solve mind-mapping hierarchy in form of a form?

Tags: forms, distributions

Any suggestions on how to solve the following problem?

Okay, I am creating a site in which there is a form. This form has several categories, and in each category, you are creating items. These items depend on each other: there's "Category one", which is kind of a 'root category'. You create how many items you want in this category. Then, in "Category two", you can create how many branches you want from the category item before "Category one", and so forth in the next categories. *The set-up is kinda like a mindmap.*
This is hard to explain in words only, so here is an illustration in hopes for better understanding:
[image: Sheet]

Hope you understand my concept. The question is: **How can i solve this in Drupal?** I know there are mind-mapping solutions to this, but unless these are very customizable, it might not be ideal. The thing is that I want to break the "add new" process into *individual modules*. That way I can create a wizard which guides the user into adding new activities, product and consequences. Also: is this do-able from any known wizard plugins or scripts? (I am using Open Atrium)